# Не понятен результат выполнения программы

Tags: c#

Сразу хочу извиниться за глупый вопрос. Сегодня первый день как начал читать книгу Г. Шилдта с# полное руководство. Не понятен результат выполнения программы. За ранее благодарен.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow. Посчитайте вручную. ("За ранее благодарен" - а за "позднее"?)

Comment: Спасибо, даже в голову не приходило.

Comment: Пожалуйста, замените картинки в вопросе на текстовые код и выходной листинг.

Comment: вроде бы всё правильно работает. За код отдельное фи. Зачем разделять объявление и инициализацию, почему итератор цикла вне цикла.

Comment: @pavel: Потому что Шилдт.

Comment: @VladD это плохой автор? Или что?

Comment: @pavel: Скажем так, я бы его не рекомендовал. На SO [был посвящённый этому вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391091/should-i-not-use-a-herb-schildt-book-to-learn-from), но его удалили. Вот ещё: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/C-faq/learn/ (раздел 16).

Answer (score 1):

Да тут вроде несложно. Сумма с каждым шагом увеличивается на i, а это i также увеличивается на 1:
шаг 1:sum=sum+i   (i сейчас = 1, а sum=0)         0+1=1 - это значение теперь присвоено переменной sum;
шаг 2:sum=sum+i   (i увеличилось на 1, а sum из прошлого шага =1)   1+(1+1)=3;
шаг 3:    3+(1+1+1)=6;
шаг 4:    6+(1+1+1+1)=10
и так далее. 
Когда i станет = 10 (9 шагов,поск. i=1 и с каждым шагом будет увеличиватться на 1 - нужно провести операцию 9 раз, чтоб i стало равно 10), цикл завершится и программа выдаст результат. Аналогично и с умножением. Уф...Кажется, подробней уже невозможно.